# log message to text box from other class

Tags: c#, class, composition

i have a multi line text box that i would like to log messages to from other classes

however i am getting a infinite loop in class creation.

What is the correct way of update form controls from outside the form class?

```
namespace Program
{

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        engine connEngine = new engine();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            msgLog("Connection Start Clicked");

            if (connEngine.StartConnection(txtIPAddress.Text, 8002) == false)
            {
                msgLog("Connection Start Failed"); 
            }
            else
            {
                msgLog("Connection Start Success");
            }

        }

        public void msgLog(string message)
        {
            txtMessageLog.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
        }


        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            msgLog("Form Load Success");
        }

    }

    class engine
    {
        MainForm _mainForm = new MainForm();

        public bool StartConnection(string txtIPAddress, int p)
        {
            _mainForm.msgLog("StartConnection started");
            //do something
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piotr solution is good. However, I prefer to have an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate instead in the class that wants to log. So the engine class remains independant of anything else coming from the MainForm, and everything stays loosely coupled.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    engine connEngine = new engine();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        connEngine.log = s => { msgLog(s); };
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msgLog("Connection Start Clicked");

        if (connEngine.StartConnection(txtIPAddress.Text, 8002) == false)
        {
            msgLog("Connection Start Failed"); 
        }
        else
        {
            msgLog("Connection Start Success");
        }

    }

    void msgLog(string message)
    {
        txtMessageLog.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
    }


    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msgLog("Form Load Success");
    }

}

class engine
{
    internal Action<string> log;

    public bool StartConnection(string txtIPAddress, int p)
    {
        log("StartConnection started");
        //do something
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're creating an instance of the *engine* in the main form and an instance of the *MainForm* in the *engine* - this creates the loop. Instead of creating new instance of the *MainForm* in the *engine*, please consider passing it as a parameter to the *engine's* constructor. Something like this (not tested):

```
class engine
{
private MainForm _mainForm = null;

engine(MainForm formInstance)
{
   _mainForm = formInstance;
}

public bool StartConnection(string txtIPAddress, int p)
{
    _mainForm.msgLog("StartConnection started");
    //do something
    return true;
}
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
       private engine connEngine = null;

       public MainForm()
       {
          InitializeComponent();

          connEngine = new engine(this);
       }

...
```

Excuse my formatting...

Answer (score 0):

you have a bit of recursion here.  `MainForm` instanciates an `engine`

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    engine connEngine = new engine();
```

and `engine` instanciates a `MainForm`

```
class engine
{
    MainForm _mainForm = new MainForm();
```

What you end up with is an infinite cycle of instantiation.